# Is there a way to forbid elements inside to go "outside"

Tags: html, css

I have a text which is an html text, and I dont know what's in (it's like a text blog actually).

What I would like to do is enclose it with a `div` with appropriate CSS so I'm sure that nothing coming from this text (especially too big pictures) can't go "outside" like this:

[image: problematic picture]

Comment: My solution was to put all in a div and do a width:100% to this div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how your elements are positioned, you should be able to use the CSS [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) attribute set to `hidden` to keep everything within a specific element actually "inside" that element :

```
.your-container {
    overflow: hidden!important;
}
```